# Object tag is not working on @media (max-width: 767px)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display a PDF file using `object` tag in HTML in both desktop and mobile. In order to make it responsive I have defined two medias - for min-768px and max-767px.

The `object` tag works fine in `@media (min-width: 768px)` but it does not work at all in `@media (max-width: 767px)`.

How to display the PDF in mobile view (`@media (max-width: 767px)`)???

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px)
```

or ,`@media screen and (min-width: 767px)`